# Venmo Deeplinking

Tags: swift, deep-linking, venmo

I have been looking into how to venmo deeplinking schemes and am **trying to open a user's account based on their username**. I looked all over the internet for this and closest I came was [this blog post](https://blog.alexbeals.com/posts/venmo-deeplinking). The person in the blog post is so close to achieving what I'm going for but I still can not figure it out. I tried changing up the "venmo://users" multiple times trying to open up a profile with a username but nothing has worked. How can I accomplish this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a tricky way to finding out Venmo's deep link to a user's account. On this site https://app.urlgeni.us/ you can paste the URL you're trying to get the deep link for and it'll provide iOS and Android information.

Also, by reviewing how it works, it provides an API (https://app.urlgeni.us/api/internal/test_url) to which you must invoke (POST method) and it'll return the deep link, by sending a JSON input as the following:

```
{"url":"venmo.com//UserName"}
```

Response will include something like:

```
    "android_scheme": "intent://user?user_id=XXXXXXX#Intent;package=com.venmo;scheme=venmo;end",
    "ios_scheme": "venmo://users/XXXXXXX"
```

Comment: These deep links appear to no longer be working (as of sometime last week).

Testing on an Android device, Venmo links like:

venmo://paycharge?txn=pay&recipients=USERNAME&note=COMMENT&amount=5

Used to open the Venmo app on android. It still opens the app, but no longer points to the user's profile at all.